# Storm UI Internal Server Error for remote cluster

Tags: apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

I'm following http://jayatiatblogs.blogspot.com/2011/11/storm-installation.html .
I try to configuring Apache Storm remote cluster in Amazon Web Services and I face the error below in my Storm UI:

```
org.apache.thrift7.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:183)
    at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81)
    at backtype.storm.thrift$nimbus_client_and_conn.invoke(thrift.clj:75)
    at backtype.storm.ui.core$cluster_configuration.invoke(core.clj:472)
    at backtype.storm.ui.core$fn__8260.invoke(core.clj:844)
```

This is my storm.yaml file for my master node at 10.0.0.230:

```
########### These MUST be filled in for a storm configuration
 storm.zookeeper.servers:
     - "10.0.0.230"
#     - "localhost"
#
 storm.zookeeper.port: 2181

 nimbus.host: "127.0.0.1"
 nimbus.thrift.port: 6627
# nimbus.task.launch.secs: 240

# supervisor.worker.start.timeout.secs: 240
# supervisor.worker.timeout.secs: 240

 ui.port: 8772

 storm.local.dir: "/home/ubuntu/storm/data"

 java.library.path: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle"

# supervisor.slots.ports:
#     - 6700
#     - 6701
#     - 6702
#     - 6703
#     - 6704

# worker.childopts: "-Xmx768m"
# nimbus.childopts: "-Xmx512m"
# supervisor.childopts: "-Xmx256m"
```

Below is my storm.yaml file for slave node at 10.0.0.79:

```
########### These MUST be filled in for a storm configuration
 storm.zookeeper.server:
     - "10.0.0.230"
#     - "localhost"
 storm.zookeeper.port: 2181

# nimbus.host: "localhost"
 nimbus.host: "10.0.0.230"
 nimbus.thrift.port: 6627
#
#ui.port: 8772
#
 storm.local.dir: "/home/ubuntu/storm/data"
 java.library.path: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle"

 supervisor.slots.ports:
     - 6700
     - 6701
     - 6702
     - 6703
#     - 6704
#
# worker.childopts: "-Xmx768m"
# nimbus.childopts: "-Xmx512m"
# supervisor.childopts: "-Xmx256m"
```

Below is my zoo.cfg file for master node:

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
dataDir=/home/ubuntu/zookeeper-data
dataLogDir=/home/ubuntu/zookeeper/log/data_log
clientPort=2181
server.1=10.0.0.230:2888:3888
autopurge.snapRetainCount=3
autopurge.purgeInterval=24
```

I had use zkServer.sh start, storm nimbus & storm ui in master node; storm supervisor in slave node. The myid for master node is 1 & the myid for slave node is 2.

What is the cause of error? how to solve it?

Comment: Problem solved. The error is due to the dataLogDir=/home/ubuntu/zookeeper/log/data_log in the zoo.cfg file. Comment the line will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The error is due to the dataLogDir=/home/ubuntu/zookeeper/log/data_log in the zoo.cfg file. Comment the line will solve the issue.

Comment: I'm glad that you solved your problem, but the thing is dataLogDir is normally a pretty important bit of configuration for Zookeeper. Particularly if you care at all about Zookeeper's performance. This solution is fine for a development / test cluster where that's not an issue, but for you'll run into trouble later. You'd probably best be served by fixing the underlying configuration. In this case the simplest solution would probably be creating a /home/ubuntu/zookeeper/log/data_log folder that the zookeeper user has write access to.